# Error 'Pride not defined' when using app.post in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Following this course on NodeJS here:
https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=api-design-nodejs-express-mongo&author=scott-moss&name=91bae158-711d-4af0-a44d-7f48435436b9&clip=3&mode=live

https://github.com/leongaban/api-design-node/blob/step-2-fix/server/server.js

I have the following simple server:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('client'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const lions = []
let id = 0

app.get('/lions', function(req, res) {
  res.json(lions)
})

app.get('/lions:id', function(req, res) {
  let paramId = req.param.id
  let lion = lions.filter((lion.id === paramId))
  res.json(lion || {})
})

app.post('/lions', function(req, res) {
  let lion = req.body
  id++
  lion.id = id + ''

  console.log('lion', lion)

  lions.push(lion)

  res.json(lion)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`NODE RUNNING on port: ${port}`))
```

In the frontend client code I am able to send the following request data:

[image]

```
age: "3"
gender: "female"
name: "1"
pride: "2"
```

However in the server my log `console.log('lion', lion)` returns just this: `lion { id: '1' }` the `req.body` is empty.

Then in the frontend console I get this error:

> VM1567:3 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: pride is not defined

Thoughts on where pride is expected? And why the `req.body` is empty on the server?

Comment: I think one potential issue is you are not also including `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Looks like the error is on client side, not server side. Better attach client code too.

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman you were right!

Comment: @LeonGaban glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use this middleware:

`app.use(bodyParser.json())`